# Do exponential identities not apply for negative numbers?

Tags: exponentiation

Recently I had a thought that got me thinking.

There is the identity $\left (a^b\right )^c=a^{bc}$.

If I now take this identity I can do this:$$(-1)=(-1)^{2\cdot 0.5}=\left ((-1)^2\right )^{0.5}=1^{0.5}=1.$$Isn't an identity supposed to be true for all values?

Interestingly if I take the part $(-1)^{0.5\cdot 2}$ I can rearange it to both:$$\left ((-1)^2\right )^{0.5}=1^{0.5}=1$$and$$\left ((-1)^{0.5}\right )^2=i^2=-1.$$So in the latter example the identity does hold true.

But isn't exponentiation supposed to be commutative? Why do I get two different solutions?

**Edit:**
As a user has pointed out in [Why $\sqrt{-1 \cdot {-1}} \neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-cdot-1-neq-sqrt-12)
The identity a^0.5*b^0.5=(a*b)^0.5 only holds true for postive numbers.

Is that also the case for the identity I used? Are all identities covering exponents only true for positive numbers?

Also what I meant with commutative was:
(a^b)^c=(a^c)^b?

Comment: As you've just discovered, exponentiation is not commutative. Consider $2^3≠3^2$.

Comment: It is not associative either: Consider $(2^2)^3 ≠ 2^{(2^3)}$.

Comment: "Isn't an identity supposed to be true for all values?" Hehe, yes, for all values *where both sides are defined*. I don't think of $\left (a^b\right )^c=a^{bc}$ as an identity because, even when both sides are defined, it is inapplicable (as you've suggested) when there's a non-positive base and non-integral exponent.

Comment: Wait so $\left (a^b\right )^c=a^{bc}$. isn't an identity after all?

Comment: Maybe call it a [conditional equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4349518/21813)? Usually an identity doesn't look wrong when it's written with three bars like this: $\left (a^b\right )^c\equiv a^{bc}.$ Semantics!

Comment: Interesting, I never got that taught in school.

Comment: Whether a formula is, or isn't, an identity depends on the setting. $x^2\ge0$ is identically true in the setting of the real numbers, but not in the setting of the complex numbers. Similar remarks apply to $\log(xy)=\log x + \log y$. $x+x=0$ is an identity in any field of characteristic two, but not in the reals.

Comment: `x+x=0  is an identity in any field of characteristic two, but not in the reals.` Wi don't understand this sentence. Isn't x+x=2x?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @GerryMyerson. So, for positive $a,b,c,$ we can indeed assert $\left (a^b\right )^c\equiv a^{bc},$ that is, that $\left (a^b\right )^c=a^{bc}$ is an identity.

Comment: $x+x=2x$, but in any field of characteristic two, $2=0$, so $x+x=0$. But maybe you are not familiar with the concept of a field of characteristic two. Are you familiar with congruences modulo two? By the way, tempdev, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson `Are you familiar with congruences modulo two?` I am afraid that my knowledge about maths does not exceed what is tought in high school, so I think that what you are talking about probably far exceeds my knowledge.  But thanks for your answer anyways!